# Solving 2nd order ODE's using Series solution method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

I have solved all the questions apart from part (d). I have also posted the general solution of y(x) which I got in terms of y1(x) and y2(x) and also in terms of coefficients a0 and a1. I am guessing that the radius of convergence will be 0 because I can see exp(-x) terms in general solution of y(x), and we all know that when we take limit (x tends to infinity), exp(-x) becomes 0 even though y(x) goes till infinity. Hence, 0 * infinity becomes 0.

Can someone please clarify this result?? If I am wrong, kindly guide me for part (d). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the ratio test to check which $x$ it converges for. It isn't actually a power series as it has exponential terms in it. My feeling is that you should have a power series as your answer, i.e. $y_i(x) = \sum a_n x^n$

Comment: Should converge for all $x$

Comment: which ratio are you trying to mean? Is it lim (x-x0)p(x) when x tends to 0, and lim (x-x0)^2.q(x) when x tends to 0 and seeing whether they exist or not?

Comment: I know that they shud converge for all x, however I am not able to show or justify that. How do I do that?